# What credential type should I use to login to AWS API?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm trying to integrate AWS API (AWSSDK 2.3.55.2) to my asp.net mvc4 project and I'm not sure what type of credential I should use. Manually i log-in to AWS using the third-party app (okta), so I don't have credentials directly from the AWS. Can I get\generate access key or smth else for login throught API by myself ? Or I should ask my AWS admin anyway to provide some creds ?

What is the simpliest way to login in this situation ?

Now I have smth like:

```
public static void RestartInstance()
        {
            var ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client();

            try
            {
                var response = ec2Client.RebootInstances(new RebootInstancesRequest
                {
                    // Frankfurt
                    InstanceIds = new List<string> {
                    "MYInstanceID"
                }
                });
            }
            catch (AmazonEC2Exception ex)
            {
                if ("InvalidInstanceID.NotFound" == ex.ErrorCode)
                {
                    Logger.Instance.Info($"AWS1 Error during rebooting. Please, check the Instance ID Ex: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
```

I have 2 choices according to client realization: http://prntscr.com/kt13al . But as far as I understand I cannot use "AWSCredentials", because I don't have this one (I log-in using another app), so I need awsAccessKeyId and awsSecretAccessKey ? Is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS has concept of IAM (Identity Access Management) for authentication and authrozation. [AWS IAM documentation.](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/)

Locally you need to have AWS Access keys(Access key and Secret access key) generated for your IAM user, this can be done for example from the AWS web console, and you need to configure the credentials. See [AWS CLI Documentation for help](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)

If you are running your application in the AWS EC2/ECS/Fargate/Elastic Beanstalk You need to specify IAM Role for the server/service to access private AWS resources. See for example [AWS documentation for EC2 IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

Configuring credentials for C# see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html#creds-assign)

Generally SDK looks for named environment variables for access key and secret key and uses them to access AWS resources.

And yes you need the access key and secret access key to locally use SDK.